# Looking for open learning material

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

in the next semester I am going to start studying some economics subjects at uni.
Since I have a little bit of time, I would like to start now already.
Does anyone know where I can find learning material about an introduction to economics, macro-economics, micro-economics, etc that is available for free on the internet and contains exercises with solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This answer has some references: https://qr.ae/pGLDkX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decent completely free materials are provided by [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/). They have videos both on basic micro and macro economics.

There are some free textbooks but they are usually not very high quality. However, you can easily find pdf versions of textbooks online if you are bit internet savvy. Good introductory economics textbook is Mankiw Principles of Economics and good intro into macro is Blanchard Macroeconomics. Both books have plenty of good examples and you should be able to find pdf version circulating out there on internet.